# Question 2.27 from Brezis' book of Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, unbounded-operators

*Question:* Let E and F be two Banach spaces and let $T\in\mathcal{L}(E,F)$. Assume
that $R(T)$ has finite codimension, i.e., there exists a finite-dimensional subspace $X$ of $F$ such that $X+R(T)=F$ and $X\cap R(T)=\{0\}$. Prove that $R(T)$ is closed.

*Solution:* Brezis' solution claims that:

> Let $G=E\times X$ and consider the operator
> $$S(x,y)=Tx+y:G\longrightarrow F.$$
> Applying the open mapping theorem, we know that $S$ is an open map, and thus $S(E\times (X\ \{0\}))=R(T)+(X\ \{0\})$ is open in $F$. Hence its complement, $R(T)$, is closed.

*Some doubts I still have:* First of all, what is the idea behind define the operator as the above? Moreover, I did not understand why $S$ is open and why this implies that $S(E\times (X\ \{0\}))=R(T)+(X\ \{0\})$ is open in $F$?

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think we should have $X / \{0\}$. Now because  $E$ is the whole spaceit is both open and closed, again $X$ is both open and closed but $X / \{0\}$ is open because as you know $\{0\}$ is closed so it's complement in $X$ is open.

Comment: Remember what open mapping theorem states. It says "if a continuous (bounded) map between banach spaces is surjective then it is open." And notice that $E  \times X$ is banach.

Comment: Lastly, i think the idea behind it is to write $F$ as a direct sum of 2 closed subspaces but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Let me put my comments into a complete answer.

**1)**  Idea behind defining the operator as above is to  be able to write $F$ as a direct sum of 2 spaces.

**2)**  Open mapping theorem states "If a continuous(bounded) map between Banach spaces is surjective then it is open." And notice $E\times X$ is Banach.

**3)** I think we should have $X/\{0\}$. Now because $E$ is the whole space it is both open and closed, again $X$ is both open and closed but $X/\{0\}$ is open because as you know $\{0\}$ is closed so it's complement in $X$ is open.